# Is there any way to add title and description while sharing something using linkedin share api?

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

i'm using linkedin share api to share a post on linkedin, but the problem is i'm not able to add title and description on it.

I using the following API :-

`https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}&title={}&description={}`

The onClick function to be called is defined below.

```
const shareViaLinkedin = () => {
window.open(
  `https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=${groupToShare}&title=${title}&description=${descrption}`,
  '_blank',
  'width=700, height=500, left=700, top=280'
  )
}
```

title and description aren't working

Even though i've tried using OG meta tags for sharing.
As mentioned in https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en

```
<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article'/>
<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg'/>
<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview'/>
<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article' />
```

But noting works! still i'm not able to add description on POST to be shared.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, these are your options, you may pick only one:

- You can display an image.
- You can display a description.

The image has priority, so if both are listed, the image will be used.  I have proof: Two weeks of arguing with the LinkedIn support staff (*[Oh the humanity...](https://www.revoltlib.com/linkedin-social-share-url-broken-ticket.html)*).

Besides that, let's try sharing a site with only a description and one with a description and image.  Wikipedia and GitHub, respectively.

[image]
[image]

**Wikipedia:** [Description Shows!  (But there is NO IMAGE)](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikipedia.org%2F)
**GitHub:** [Image Shows!  (But there is NO DESCRIPTION)](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.github.com%2F)

I made a [test site, with only description,](https://www.revoltlib.com/linkedin-social-share-url-test.html) and, similarly, it works.

After thorough testing, this seems to be the unfortunate case!  I've re-requested LinkedIn to reconsider how they do this, but I have had no success.  I'm well aware that the [Official Microsoft LinkedIn Share Documentation](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en) makes no mention whatsoever of this, but all of the real evidence seems to point in the opposite direction.